# How do I get the good ol' timezone world map back?

Tags: unity, gnome, indicator, applet, gnome2

This is the biggest thing I miss from Gnome 2 – the world map with daylight and location markers of favourite cities, followed by a list of timezones with weather status! Shame on whoever thought it was a good idea to get rid of this awesome feature:

[image: Calendar with world map and timezones.]

How do I bring some or all of it back? Is there any such Gnome 3 shell extension? Is there any way for Unity or other graphical shells?

Comment: We can always start a git repo, learn basics of widgets in gnome 3 and create a copy ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try the Mate desktop, the only thing I'm aware of that still supports it.  I recommend Ubuntu Mate.

[image: Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS]

Available at https://ubuntu-mate.org/

Of course you can install Mate on other flavors/versions with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Although it will be missing a few niceties such as a searchable menu and dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

For Unity (Ubuntu 14.04) I'd suggest a two-pronged approach:

1) Under the Time & Date settings, Clock tab, you can add other locations.  No pretty world map but at least you'll have the date/time in other places.

2) Install either `my-weather-indicator` or `indicator-weather`, both found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) and add an alternate location.